# Angular Pristine Form vs Dirty Form on new Search

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am creating a clickable form that populates another form based on that 'td' row JSON's data.  The form takes two inputs Monday and Tuesday.  I reset(clear) the form using pristine and that works fine.  I am having trouble clearing the form on second search.  Example: Type Monday, click Search, click Monday, now type Tuesday...when I click Search I want Monday's information removed.  How do I do this?  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/al321/s4cLbL19/16/).

```
 Reset Function: 
 var clearResults = angular.copy($scope.results);
 var clearRowItems = angular.copy($scope.rowItems);

 $scope.reset = function ()
 {
  $scope.enteredValue = '';
  $scope.results = '';

  $scope.results = angular.copy(clearResults);
  $scope.rowItems = angular.copy(clearRowItems);
  $scope.personForm.$setPristine();
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
$scope.enteredValue = '';
```

to the bottom of the `clickButton` function.

http://jsfiddle.net/e5u1jz6b/

So, once `clickButton` function does what it does, the above code will clear your search field in the view (in this case by setting it to an empty string).

This works both ways - when you type something in the form, it changes the value of `enteredValue`, but also - if you change the `enteredValue` in the controller, it will automatically update in the view.

It's called two-way data binding:
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04

Answer (score 0):

When you are hitting search, you are only pushing more items to your results array.  You are not clearing the previous results array so every time you click search, it will just keep adding to 'results'

An easy solution would be to just reset 'results' to an empty array to clear it out at the top of your 'clickbutton' function.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, invoking .reset() will clear the previous values for the given scenario:

> Example: Type Monday, click Search, click Monday, now type Tuesday...when I click Search I want Monday's information removed.

```
$scope.clickButton = function (enteredValue) {
  // clear previous values 'Monday' information 
  // from above scenario'
  $scope.reset(); 
  $scope.items = $scope.stuff;
  .
  .
}
```

Hope this helps.